# Azure Stream Analytics Job - Transformation Query - correct formatting in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-stream-analytics

When editing a Stream Analytics transformation query in the Portal, you can format it for readability across multiple lines...e.g.

```
SELECT 
INTO [Output1]
FROM [Input1]
PARTITION BY PartitionId
WHERE etc etc etc
```

When putting this into an ARM template for CI/CD, this is entered as one massive long string and would end up displaying in the portal as...

```
SELECT * INTO [Output1] FROM [Input1] PARTITION BY PartitionId WHERE etc etc etc to infinity....
```

The official documentation is pretty useless and doesn't give any clues for the query part of the template, just that it is a "string"...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.streamanalytics/2016-03-01/streamingjobs/transformations

There is a Microsoft sample template that is the only example I could find with a transform query specified... 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-streamanalytics-create/azuredeploy.json
...and it looks like it is trying to do spacing...

```
"query": "SELECT\r\n    *\r\nINTO\r\n    [YourOutputAlias]\r\nFROM\r\n    [YourInputAlias]"
```

...but failing badly - see screenshot

Has anyone managed to do this?

Also does anyone know why you can see the transformation query in the Azure Resource Explorer (https://resources.azure.com/)? Or that it cannot be exported from the portal with the rest of the Stream Job? (done at Resource Group level)

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is a full year later and perhaps you've figured this out already, however, this is what I did:

In my **Parameters** file, I used an array of strings, for example:

```
"StreamAnalyticsJobQueryMultiline": {
    "value": [
    "WITH allData AS ( ",
    "    SELECT ",
    "        *, ",
    "        GetMetadataPropertyValue([%%INPUTSTREAMNAME%%], '[User].[EventNamespace]') AS EventNamespace ",
    "    FROM [%%INPUTSTREAMNAME%%] Partition By PartitionId ",
    "SELECT ",
    "    *, ",
    "    'EventHubWriterv1' AS EventType ",
    "INTO ",
    "    [%%OUTPUTSTREAMNAME%%] ",
    "FROM ",
    "    allData Partition By PartitionId "
    ]
```

When the array is concatenated, and output as a string, it produces something like this, where each item in that array is still enclosed by the quotation marks and the entire thing is contained within square braces (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#concat)

> ["Foo","Bar","Blah"]

So additional transformation in order to turn it into something readable in the Stream Analytics output is required.
Also note here the %%INPUTSTREAMNAME%% and %%OUTPUTSTREAMNAME%%, as both my input and output streams are also parameters, and using the typical inline [parameter('ParamName')] did not work nicely with the rest of the transformation needed.

In my **Template** file, I take the *StreamAnalyticsJobQueryMultiline* parameter and use the variables field to do this transformation:

```
"QueryStringRaw":  "[string(concat(parameters('StreamAnalyticsJobQueryMultiline')))]",
    
// Update the end-of-lines by removing the doublequote and comma, and replacing it with a newline character 
"QueryStringIter1": "[replace(variables('QueryStringRaw'), '\",', '\n')]",

// Update the beginning-of-lines by removing the doublequote
"QueryStringIter2": "[replace(variables('QueryStringIter1'), '\"', '')]",

// Update the InputStreamName and OutputStreamName values
"QueryStringIter3": "[replace(variables('QueryStringIter2'), '%%INPUTSTREAMNAME%%', parameters('InputStreamName'))]",
"QueryStringIter4": "[replace(variables('QueryStringIter3'), '%%OUTPUTSTREAMNAME%%', parameters('OutputStreamName'))]",

// Produce the final output for the query string by trimming the leading and trailing square brackets
"QueryStringFinal": "[substring(variables('QueryStringIter4'), 1, sub(length(variables('QueryStringIter4')), 2))]"
```

Then I reference that in the transformation portion of the Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs properties:

```
"transformation": {
    "name": "Transformation",
    "properties": {
        "streamingUnits": "[parameters('StreamAnalyticsStreamingUnitsScale')]",
        "query": "[variables('QueryStringFinal')]"
    }
}
```